# how to use getText() to get text from field in a different class

Tags: java, swing, authentication, jbutton, gettext

Hi I am trying to take user input for a login form. I have a `JTextField` called `textField,` I would like to take the user input and use it in another class.

```
`public String useridGet() 
 {
    return textField.getText();
}
public String userpasswordGet()
  {
    return passwordField.getText();
}`
```

I have these two methods to return the `userid` and `user password` from the login form.

```
`Button btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        {
                       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                  {
                 loginConnect loginConnectObject = new loginConnect();
                                   loginConnectObject.verifyDetails();
}                               }
});`
```

I then in the log in button used the `verifyDetails()` method from the `loginConnect` class to collect the data to compare with the database.

```
`public void verifyDetails()
    {
        loginScreen loginScreenObject = new loginScreen();
        String userid = loginScreenObject.useridGet();
        String userpassword = loginScreenObject.userpasswordGet();
        System.out.println("testing "+userid+userpassword);
    }`
```

In the `verifyDetails()` method i have tried to create a object of the `loginScreen` class to access the `getText` methods which collect the input from the login form.

This doesnt seam to be working and Im not sure where I am going wrong, any hints. please, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem...

```
loginConnect loginConnectObject = new loginConnect();
```

You keep creating new instance of the `loginConnect` class, which means the one that is on the screen isn't the instance you are trying access, they have no relationship together.

Instead, you could make `loginConnect` an instance variable and reference it from within your main class, for example...

```
public class ...
    private loginConnect loginConnectObject;

    public ... {
        //...
        loginConnectObject = new loginConnect();
        add(loginConnectObject);
        //...
        Button btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
        btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                loginConnectObject.verifyDetails();
            }
        });
        //...
```

You may also want to take a read through [Naming conventions for the Java Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html), as it will make your code easier for people to read...